# JQuery if statements?

Tags: jquery

New to JQuery and was wondering how can I put the following JQuery code in an if statement so that it only runs when the submit button is clicked and does nothing when not clicked I know I'm using the `$(".save-button").click(function()` is there a way to put it in an if statement?

JQuery code.

```
$(function() {
    $(".save-button").click(function() {
        $.post($("#contact-form").attr("action"), $("#contact-form").serialize(), function(html) {
            $("div.contact-info-form").html(html);
            $('#changes-saved').append('<li>Changes saved!</li>').show().pause(1000).hide();
        });
        return false; // prevent normal submit
    });
});
```

Comment: This isn't very clear... What condition do you need? Of course `click` does nothing when you don't click it...

Answer (score 3):

calling .click and passing a function says "call this function when the element is clicked"

.click() without a function argument calls the click event

Therefore, there is no need for an 'if'

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can check the `type` attribute of the clicked element e.g.:

```
//...
if ($(this).attr('type') == 'submit')
//...
```

But I would recommend you to use the`submit` event, remember that the form can be also submitted if the user presses Enter:

```
$(function() {
    $("#contact-form").submit(function() {
        var $form = $(this);
        $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function(html) {
            $("div.contact-info-form").html(html);
            $('#changes-saved').append('<li>Changes saved!</li>').show()
                               .pause(1000).hide();
        });
        return false; // prevent normal submit
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".save-button").click(function() {
    $.post($("#contact-form").attr("action"), $("#contact-form").serialize(), function(html) {
        $("div.contact-info-form").html(html);
        $('#changes-saved').append('<li>Changes saved!</li>').show().pause(1000).hide();
    });
    return false; // prevent normal submit
});
```

This will bind the click event to any element with .save-button class.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply it only to submit buttons:

```
$(".save-button:submit")
```